# Using RackSpace to store data from 1,000 iPhones without "sharing"

Tags: iphone, sandbox, cloud-hosting, rackspace

Is there a simple way to have all my users of an app have a part of RackSpace for some of their information, let's say key'ed by their UUID (an id unique to their iPhone), with that data encrypted just for them?

That way, all 1,000 could upload and download info, and if they wanted, could forward their info to me via that cloud.  And if they freak out, they can destroy their cloud's data for their UUID.

Is this written, or do I have to write it?  Can it use SQLite?  Or should / can I use a csv attachment to an email to the RackSpace Cloud, that is public key encrypted?

In other words, can they each have their own sandbox, which may be quite small (50,000 bytes)?

And can there be 1 row per user, with the option that they can send up detailed info (10 megs of thousands of records) now and again if they run into a bug in my code?

Comment: FYI, Apple are deprecating the use of obtaining a UDID, so it would be best to come up with a different identifier.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate that you told me this.  And you're right: "Apple phasing out iOS UDID access to solve privacy woes", August 23, 2011 by Devindra  http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/23/ios-5-udid-privacy/

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Parse](http://www.parse.com) it is a no sql freeform database in the cloud

Answer (score 0):

Look at iCloud.   We can't talk about yet on here (because it is still under NDA).  If you are an Apple developer, you can read the documentation there.